# Is it possible to update a single nested property on a DeviceTwin such that the siblings lastUpdated property is not updated?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have a device property that looks like this:

"{ Status : {
Property1: "111",
Property2: "222"
}
}"

How do I update just Property2 using the C# TwinCollection class ?

I I use the code below then "Property2" properties lastUpdated value changes even though it was not updated.

```
   var status = new TwinCollection();
   status["Property1"] = "111";
   
   var reportedProperties = new TwinCollection();
   reportedProperties["status"] = status;

   await deviceClient.UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync(reportedProperties);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This answer is made with the assumption that you mean "update Property1", because that's what your code sample states.

I just created a new West Europe IoT hub, created a new device with Device Twin that you specified (with a lowercase 's' in 'Status', your code specifies a lower case, but your question mentioned an uppercase).

I then ran your code, and the resulting metadata is:

```json
"$metadata": {
    "$lastUpdated": "2023-08-20T10:05:51.8902538Z",
    "status": {
        "$lastUpdated": "2023-08-20T10:05:51.8902538Z",
        "Property1": {
            "$lastUpdated": "2023-08-20T10:05:51.8902538Z"
        },
        "Property2": {
            "$lastUpdated": "2023-08-20T10:05:40.8567787Z"
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `$lastUpdated` changed in all instances, but not for `Property2`.

Comment: Oh, maybe that just a man look on my part ??  Let me do a proper look at that.

So I was under the impression that the Twin object retrieved by the deviceClient would automatically update - conceptually I must be missing something here - how does the client itself get notified when there is a desired change requested by the cloud ?  Does the client also have to register a separate listener to the separate event hub created for handling DeviceTwin change events ? I hope not - seems like a lot of additional stuff given the client already has access to its Twin.

Comment: So the usual pattern is:
1. device boots up
2. device retrieves its twin
3. device subscriptes to updates on desired state

[Here's a sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/a84c614e98fd2259a965e7385b92c6d96043de57/iothub/device/samples/getting%20started/TwinSample/TwinSample.cs#L33) on how to subscribe to changes

Comment: Thanks - helps if you know where to look !  Is it not possible to do the same thing on the Hub side of things ? Get the device Twin and then subscribe to property changes without the need route change events to another message hub and then filtering for the one you want ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. There's always going to be custom code involved, sorry. It's not a feature of IoT Hub.

Comment: Thanks for the help - its up and running, just need to try out the provisioning service.